# Display units in a Number Column while retaining Thousands Seperator

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm trying to adjust the way that a SharePoint Number Column displays its value so that it can include a specific unit of measurement. I want people to enter into the field only a Number, but for the column to display with the suffix " ft²".

I've managed to accomplish this using column formatting with the following JSON:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": {
        "operator": "+",
        "operands": [
            "@currentField",
            " ft²"
        ]
    }
}
```

However, this removes the thousands separator. So for a value entered of "10000" into the column displays as "10000 ft²" instead of "10,000 ft²".

Any suggestions for appending a unit to a Number column so that it retains the thousand separator?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could create a calculated column and add the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(Num,"#,###"),"ft²")
```

Test result:

[image]